# $(n+1)$th derivative by differentiating

Tags: calculus

I've tried to answer this question many time but always wrong so can you help me please ? 
 Thanks

Let $f(x) = \ln(1 + x)$.

Use mathematical induction to prove that the
following statement is true.

$$f^{n}(x) = \frac{(−1)^{n+1} (n − 1)!}{(1 + x)^n}$$
 for all $n ∈ \mathbb N$.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating $f^{(n)}$????

Comment: @copper.hat Ooooh, take it easy. Not too fast. That may solve the problem.

Comment: @ClementC.: I am not a fan of indolence :-).

Comment: Well, if one does not try anything, then one won't make any mistake, right?

Comment: I keep trying to learn by making mistakes, but have found that repeating the same mistake doesn't make the learning go faster :-).

Comment: Yes I did differentiating and got 1/x+1 ?!

Comment: @Yassmin for the induction step, you differentiate $f^{(n)}$, not $f$.

Comment: OK I'll try now

Answer (score 3):

Induction start
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}.$$
Induction step
\begin{align*}f^{(n)}(x)=(f^{(n-1)})'(x)&=\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}(n-2)!}{(1+x)^{n-1}}\right)' \\ & =\frac{(-1)^{n}(n-2)!}{(1+x)^{n}}\cdot (-(n-1))\\ &=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^{n}}\end{align*}
Where I only used that $(x^k)'=k\cdot x^{k-1},\forall k\neq 0$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I presume because the policy is to answer only if effort is shown. In this case I must admit to have decided to answer anyway because the OP said to have tried to solve the problem, so I believed him.

Comment: Also, there appears to be a typo. the $n-1!$ should be $(n-2)!$, shouldn't it? (two occurrences)

Comment: absolutely. I'll correct it straight away. (I was typing from my phone... not funny, I'll tell you)

Comment: I think downvoters should provide reasons.

Comment: So this is the last answer ?!

Comment: What do you mean? This is *an* answer, which gives a proof of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$f^{(n+1)}(x) = (f^{(n)}(x))' = \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}\right)' = \quad???$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\ln(1+x)$$ and
$$f^{n}(x) = \frac{(−1)^{n+1} (n − 1)!}{(1 + x)^n}$$ be the statement.

Clearly $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{(−1)^{1+1} (1 − 1)!}{(1 + x)^1}$$

Thus the result is true for $n=1$.

Now suppose that the result is true for $n=p$.

That is $$f^{p}(x) = \frac{(−1)^{p+1} (p − 1)!}{(1 + x)^p}$$

Now observe that ,

$$f^{p+1}(x)=\frac{d[f^{p}(x)]}{dx} $$

$$f^{p+1}(x)=\frac{d\left[\frac{(−1)^{p+1} (p − 1)!}{(1 + x)^p}\right]}{dx} $$

$$f^{p+1}(x)=(−1)^{p+1} (p − 1)!\frac{d\left[\frac{1}{(1 + x)^p}\right]}{dx} $$

$$f^{p+1}(x)=(−1)^{p+1} (p − 1)!\frac{(-p)}{(x+1)^{p+1}} $$

$$f^{p+1}(x)=(−1)^{(p+1)}(-1)^1 (p − 1)!(p)\frac{1}{(x+1)^{p+1}} $$

$$f^{p+1}(x)=\frac{(−1)^{(p+1)+1} \left((p+1)-1\right)!}{(x+1)^{p+1}} $$